# How to implement a moving window analysis?

Tags: python

I want to apply a "moving window analysis" to split raw EEG data into segments of smaller duration for feature extraction as described in this paper:

[A Multi-view Deep Learning Framework for EEG Seizure Detection](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/327855474_A_Multi-view_Deep_Learning_Framework_for_EEG_Seizure_Detection)

In this paper they segment EEG signals into several fixed length slots by sliding a "L-length" window. What is the python code should I use?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to help you here, we'll need to see what you've tried. This forum is more meant to help you work out specific issues with your code, not to answer general questions.

Comment: Haven't read the paper, but I once used a [`collections.dequeue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) to implement a fixed-size "moving window" that got used to calculate a "running/moving average" of the group of values currently within it — so perhaps that approach would also work for doing this.